# Minikube - monitor persistent storage usage

Tags: minikube

I would like to see if there are potential issues with disk size usage with Minikube.
As per my understanding, Minikube allocates 20GB of storage by default and I can control that via  the disk size flag: `minikube start --vm-driver=hyperkit --disk-size=40g`
Further I can control the size a container can allocate via something like this:

```
  spec:
  containers:
  - name: app
    image: ...
    resources:
      requests:
        ephemeral-storage: "2Gi"
      limits:
        ephemeral-storage: "4Gi"
```

So I could have a maximum of 20/4=5 of these containers running.
With this in mind how can I now check directly how much storage of those total 20GB is still available on Minikube and how much of the 4GB the container is using?
Also, in case any container fails due to using more storage, is there a command that shows after the fact if any of the containers in the cluster has failed due to running out of storage? Something akin to `minikube events --show-failures out-of-storage`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no minikube commands available for checking the disk utilization as of now according to this [official github issue request](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/12967), you either need to use some **monitoring tools** for checking the disk utilization of minikube vms and containers or you need to manually login to each vm or container for checking the disk utilizations. You can either use normal ssh or use **minikube ssh** as shown in this git [comment.](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/8422#issuecomment-641358719)

If any pod or container failed because of **an out of storage issue** you can check the [**minikube logs**](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/commands/logs/) or you can use the below kubernetes command for checking the reason due to which a pod exited with a failure status.

```
kubectl get pods
```

Comment: Excellent, `minikube logs` should be what I was looking for, thanks! `kubectl get pods` is too cumbersome since I don't want to manually iterate through all pods.
I did try `minikube ssh` but maybe I am misunderstanding something `minikube ssh "df -h"` shows something very similar to the host system. I would expect to see a volume with the default size of 20G but don't.

Comment: Hi @phobic as mentioned in the git comment you can use `du` which gives the total disk utilization instead of using `df -h` which gives the details of the entire filesystem.

Comment: Thanks, I don't see /dev/sda1 or /mnt/sda1 in my output. If I understand it correctly the strategy described in the git comment is more or less to sum up the allocated storage under the directories described in https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/persistent_volumes/ and then calculate the usage based on the default allocation of 20GB. So it's an indirect way of checking the disk utilization.